# Lua: set of k-dimensional points

Tags: lua, set, point

I want to make sure that kD points which I generate randomly don't happen to be identical. To test this efficiently, I want to use a set (at least that's what I would do in C++).

I know that in Lua tables can be used as sets by inserting the object as value with any non-nil key (typically just *true* or an integer for multisets). 
But the problem is that tables in Lua are by default just compared w.r.t. their address, which is of course different even if all the vector components (in my case) are equal.

So I thought I'd implement a *equal* and/or *less than* metamethod for my points. But this didn't work (see code below). Can anybody help?

```
local k = 3
local mt = {}

mt.__eq = function( a, b )
    for dim = 1, k do
        if a[dim] ~= b[dim] then return false end
    end
    return true
end

mt.__lt = function( a, b )
    for dim = 1, k do
        if     a[dim] < b[dim] then
            return true
        elseif a[dim] > b[dim] then
            return false
        end
    end
    return false -- equal
end

local set = {}

local p1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
setmetatable( p1, mt )
set[p1] = true

local p2 = { 1, 2, 3 }
setmetatable( p2, mt )
set[p2] = true -- should just overwrite the old value

print( "p1 == p2 --> "..tostring( p1 == p2 ) )
print( "p1 <  p2 --> "..tostring( p1 <  p2 ) )

local setSize = 0
for _, _ in pairs( set ) do
    setSize = setSize + 1
end
print( "Size of the set: "..setSize )
```

Comment: "at least that's what I would do in C++" I wouldn't do that in C++, let alone Lua. The performance would be terrible.

Comment: In this line `set[p2] = true -- should just overwrite the old value` another key-value pair will be created.  Even if two objects are equal according to your metamethod, they still remain different according to table indexing.  Possible workaround: sort the array of objects (using table.sort) and then remove duplicates (check every adjacent pair for equality).

Comment: Another solution: use strings as table keys: replace `set[p1] = true` with `set[table.concat(p1,';')] = true`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff But I guess that the equality then depends on the accuracy of the implicit tostring() of the floating point vector components.

Comment: If you use __index and __index on 'set' you could effectively do what you're trying to do. But it's rather inefficient for such a small task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua has no facilities for allowing what you're trying to do. That is, there's no metamethod trickery that can make two different pieces of userdata or two different tables map to the same index to the table indexing system.

You'll have to do this manually. You can effectively write your own set, by keeping a list of vectors sorted. `table.sort` can do the job, since you already have an appropriate `__lt` metamethod.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Thanks for the practical work-around though.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested: I have come up with another work-around that has worked for me.

One can use a set of x-coordinates and instead of associating the set items with just "true" or "1", the respective values are sets themselves (of y-coordinates); and so on.

This leads to a tree-like structure where the path to each leaf represents a point (sequence of coordinates) and points with the same first coordinates have common parent nodes. Also all points are unique.